# Using TV as monitor for my Android phone

Tags: hdmi, mhl

I have thought of using my TV as a monitor before and today I saw an RCA to USB cable in my garage and wondered whether it would work if I plug that into my OTG or Lightning "connector". And also, would it just work straight away or is there software involved.
Please help

Comment: Was there a failure when you tried it? Any results to edit onto the question?

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work. I do suspect that the USB to rca cable I have might be faulty. I think I would rather just buy a decent hdmi converter for my phone.

Comment: Have you seen the adapter only or a working set-up? If I get it right RCA is an old analogue connector used for audio or video but also for various over analogue signals. I remember such connectors with old digital cameras but they were device specific and proprietary. Never heard of an Android phone that had such an adapter.